# PHP using urlencode results in Page Not Found error

Tags: php, url, urlencode, encode

I'm having a problem that's probably (hopefully) very easy to solve but I'm just about stuck.

When I use the urlencode (or rawurlencode) function it will not find he script I'm sending it too.

So this works fine:

```
$data["text"] .= "<a href='index.php?load=results&reg=".$row["region"]."'>".$row["region"]."</a><br/>";
```

And it will take me to the correct page:

**index.php?load=results&reg=CRO**

But the person I'm doing the job is having her "&" symbol replaced with a (R) registered symbol, and she is getting a page not found. Unfortunately I'm unable to reproduce this on any of the other computers in this office

So when i change the code to read

```
$data["text"] .= "<a href='".urlencode("index.php?load=results&reg=".$row["region"])."'>".$row["region"]."</a><br/>";
```

It tries to take me to this page

**index.php%3Fload%3Dresults%26reg%3DCRO**

But it gives me the following page not found error:

***The requested URL index.php?load=results&reg=CRO was not found on this server.***

Which is really weird because the requested URL is exactly the same as the URL which resolves no bother up the top. I understand I'll need to run urldecode (or rawurldecode) at some stage but if it isn't even finding a script to load I can't run that function anyway...

EDIT: Further details - I am coding on a Mac using TextWranger. The file is encoded using utf8 with Unix (LF) Line Endings. The local server is using MAMP and the live server is a Windows based machine but I'm not sure of any configuration settings that could help as I've just started here. The output HTML is encoded with UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you use it:

```
$data["text"] .= "<a href='index.php?load=results&reg=".urlencode($row["region"])."'>".$row["region"]."</a><br/>";
```

What you are doing is urlencoding the values of you parameters, not the whole query.

So basically:

```
$data = "index.php?key=".urlencode("hello world value");
// will result in:
"index.php?key=hello%20world%20value"
```

Comment: Cheers. I'll give it a go and see how it goes, but it seems its the & symbol that appears to be the problem. I'm only ever retrieving the values CRO, ERO, NRO, SRO and WA for the value $row["region"] - It will at least work for me but whether it works on her end I don't know. It could be a different issue all together

Answer (score 1):

According to the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/notes.html#non-ascii-chars):

> Although URIs do not contain non-ASCII values (see [URI], section 2.1) authors sometimes specify them in attribute values expecting URIs (i.e., defined with %URI; in the DTD). For instance, the following href value is illegal:

So essentially you should **not be using non-ASCII characters in your URI**, since different user agents will handle them differently.

For example, the user agent may decide to use the document's character-set encoding or it may assume an html-entity encoding. Which is probably what your user mentioned they experienced. So the best thing to do is make sure you always supply ASCII characters in the `href` attribute of an `a` tag by urlencoding the entire URI part of your URL.

If you're assembling this URL on the fly, each time, one function in PHP that can help you take care of the whole ordeal is [http_build_query](http://php.net/http-build-query), which puts together the query string for you and properly url-encodes it.

```
$row["region"] = "CRO";
$query = array(
                  "load" => "results",
                  "reg"  => $row["region"],
              );
$query = http_build_query($query);

echo $URL = "index.php?" . $query; // index.php?load=results&reg=CRO
```

Now you can use

```
echo "<a href=\"$URL\">{$row['region']}</a>";
```

and you get...

```
<a href="index.php?load=results&reg=CRO">CRO</a>
```

Comment: Cheers mate, I looked at the http_build_query function and that looks useful and something I'll look at implementing.  What turned out to be the issue was Internet Explorer (surprise!!) was taking the &reg part of my string and changing that to a (R) registered symbol even though it should only do that with &reg; ... I really don't have time to work out why it would do that so I changed the paramater from reg to region. Such a stupid thing to cause such headache today!!

Comment: That does sound silly :) I'm glad you fixed your issue though.

Answer (score 0):

The question mark is used as a separator and is not part of the query string.

You can't enecode character "?" Character "?" is not part of query string.

Of course you are free to encode any part of query string

Try:

```
<?php
echo "<a href='get.php?".urlencode("load=results&reg=".urlencode($row["region"])."'>".$row["region"]."</a><br/>";
var_dump($_GET);
?>
```